# Independence of path in line integral

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-integration, parametrization, line-integrals

Let $\gamma: [a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ be a map that is of bounded variation and $f:G\subseteq \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous map on a domain containing $\gamma([a,b])$. Then we define the line integral of $f$ with respect to the curve $\gamma$ as the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

$$\int_\gamma f(z) dz =\int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) d\gamma(t)$$

When $\gamma$ is piecewise smooth, it can be shown that this last integral is equal to

$$\int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$$

Question: I see people write: calculate the line integral over a certain line segment. Does that mean the parametrisation of the curve doesn't matter? More formally, let  $\eta: [c,d]\to \mathbb{C}$ another parametrisation with $\gamma([a,b])=\eta([c,d])$. Is it true that

$$\int_\gamma f =\int_\eta f$$

In my book, "functions of one complex variable" by Conway, it is proven that this is true if $\eta =\gamma \circ \phi$ for a non-decreasing surjective continuous function $\phi:[c,d]\to [a,b]$.

For example, ex 13 in the line integral chapter in my book asks me to find

$$\int_\gamma z^{-1/2}dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the upper half of the unit circle from +1 to -1. Such a wording suggests that the parametrisation shouldn't matter (as long as it is piecewise smooth, I guess) right? Or maybe the author assumes I use a canonical parametrisation?

Comment: Change of variable formula shows integral is same regardless of parametrization

Comment: @Conrad Doesn't change of variable formula not imply that we can write one function as composition of the other one?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - two parametric representations of the same path give an isomorphic ( same degree of differentiability both for the map and its inverse) map between the parametrization intervals, so parametrization doesn't really matter as long as it is sufficiently smooth

Comment: Can you provide a reference for that?

Comment: Any basic topology or CV text should have it - now on phone but when home can look up in my library, though at a guess Conway or Rudin should have that; anyway just write it up as $\gamma^{-1} \circ \delta$, where $\gamma, \delta$ are the parametrizations, so it is a 1-1 onto smooth map between intervals which preserves orientation, hence it is increasing to (if you change orientation, integral switches signs)

Comment: I just checked Conway and Rudin's real and complex analysis and it does not provide this statement, but maybe I just don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: See my comment -prove that the composition there works; if you work on continuos but piecewise smooth only curves, split them into smooth parts and use integral additivity

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Conrad I added an answer to the question.

Comment: Excellent and happy you found a solution

Comment: Thank you for your help! What I was missing was injectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. @Conrad gave some hints in the comments and eventually I found the following theorem in Apostol's mathematical analysis, which also answers my question.

**Theorem:** Let $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (the same proof works with codomain $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}^2)$ two injective maps. Then $f$ and $g$ are equivalent iff they have the same graph.